# Make INDIRECT draggable across a row using ADDRESS?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make my indirect formula draggable across a row, I have tried using **ADDRESS** function but I can't seem to get it work right for me:

```
=COUNTIFS(C$3:INDIRECT("C"&$B$65),"2",$A$3:INDIRECT("A"&$B$65),"*&*")
```

At the moment I am manually editting the formula for each cell, but I am sure there is a way of getting the drag to work?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Can you share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) with example of your data and desired result?

Comment: @z..: That's a nice utility. Is there a post with the link that I can bookmark?

Comment: @Argyll, which link are you referring to?

Comment: Sample Doc:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kvHfKNBnTV4oN6cXvpC2uSFLaz7DHe_Uz0JBY5lTeho/edit#gid=0

I would like to drag the formular in C16 to the right ..

This cell shows the number of cells in the above column that have a "2" in it as well as the associated cell in column A that has "&" in it

The "Rows' in B18 is to know how many rows there are that potentially have names in them, so that extra rows can be inserted.

Comment: @z..: the form that creates shared sheet

Comment: @Argyll, I bookmarked the link that I shared above.

Comment: @z..: Ah I can do that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=countifs(C3:index(C:C,$B18),"2",$A3:index($A:$A,$B18),"*&*")
```

[image]